# Selecting multiple options in unchanging url

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I need to scrape content from the [website](http://swachhbharatmission.gov.in/tsc/Report_NBA/Panchayat/Rpt_SarpanchDetail.aspx) by selecting state, district and blocks from the drop down menus.

I tried using python requests and posts, but I'm not able to scrape the content properly as the url of the website never changes for the options i choose.

This is the code I've tried so far :

```py
# importing all necessary packages
import urllib3
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

url = "http://swachhbharatmission.gov.in/tsc/Report_NBA/Panchayat/Rpt_SarpanchDetail.aspx"
session = requests.Session()
html = session.get(url, verify=False).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
option = soup.find("select",{"name":"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlState"}).findAll("option")

# create dictionary 'states' mapping each state with it's code
states = {}
for elem in option[1:]:
    key = elem['value']
    value = elem.text
    states[key] = value

for state in states.keys():
    payload_ano = {'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlState': str(state)}
    r = requests.post(url, data=payload_ano,verify=False)
    break

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
option = soup.find("select",{"name":"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlDistrict"}).findAll("option")

option # only gives [<option selected="selected" value="%">All District</option>] from the home page and not the districts inside the state chosen
```

I have used a break statement so the code can terminate earlier. Now the problem is that the variable `option` in the final line should contain the content of the drop down list when the state was chosen. But it only shows the content of the home page.

Any help or suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't get access to the URL! Is it working ?

Comment: @AaronS, it is working (http://swachhbharatmission.gov.in/tsc/Report_NBA/Panchayat/Rpt_SarpanchDetail.aspx)

Comment: `onchange="javascript:setTimeout` The dropdown menus seem to be using javascript, is it not possible to scrape this through python-requests. Should I try using selenium or scraping with javascript or node.js (I have no experience in scraping with node.js)

Comment: That was going to be my suggestion, selenium unless there’s a hidden api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use selenium to select an option from the drop downs.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('http://swachhbharatmission.gov.in/tsc/Report_NBA/Panchayat/Rpt_SarpanchDetail.aspx')

# get state options
state_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlState"]')
state_select = Select(state_element)
state_options = [state_option.text for state_option in state_select.options]

# choose state option number
print('\nselect state:')
for i, state in enumerate(state_options):
    print(f'{i+1} - {state.strip()}')
state = input(':- ')

# select state option
state_selected = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlState"]/option[{state}]')
state_selected.click()

# get district options
district_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlDistrict"]')
district_select = Select(district_element)
district_options = [district_option.text for district_option in district_select.options]

# choose district option number
print('\nselect district:')
for i, district in enumerate(district_options):
    print(f'{i+1} - {district.strip()}')
district = input(':- ')

# select district option
district_selected = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlDistrict"]/option[{district}]')
district_selected.click()

# get block options
block_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlBlock"]')
block_select = Select(block_element)
block_options = [block_option.text for block_option in block_select.options]

# choose block option number
print('\nselect block:')
for i, block in enumerate(block_options):
    print(f'{i+1} - {block.strip()}')
block = input(':- ')

# select block option
block_selected = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlBlock"]/option[{block}]')
block_selected.click()


# get data of each record
try:
    table_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('table.Table')
except NoSuchElementException:
    print('\nRecord not found')
else:
    table_rows = table_element.find_elements_by_css_selector('table.Table tr')
    print('\nGrampanchayat Sarpanch Details')
    for table_row in table_rows[2:]:
        table_cols = table_row.find_elements_by_css_selector('table.Table tr td')
        for table_col in table_cols:
            print(table_col.text, end=',\t')
        print()
```

Note:
You need to download [Chrome Driver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) into your project folder.